# React Native emulator suddenly stops connecting to the Metro server

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-studio

Would anyone suspect why my React Native app on the emulator just suddenly stop working and show a "No connection to the Metro server error" out of the blue?

The screenshots refer to the same error. The longer message one is what comes up after I refresh the emulator.

[image: First error]

[image: Second error after refresh]

System: MacOS 14.2.1
Android Studio: Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 1
Node: 18.15.0
I can give setting of the emulator too but don't know how relevant they are since the emulator has worked 75% of the times

I have still to find a pattern on when it decides to go awol on me but here's what has worked in the past.

- First time it happened: Just restarting the emulator and the Metro server worked
- Second time it happened: Just restarting the emulator and the Metro server DID NOT work. I had to run adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 which worked.
- Third time it happened(now): None of the above works in any capacity or order

Disclaimer: I have tried restarting everything, restarting by clearing cache on npx react-native, closing the emulator, closing the Metro server, closing the terminals, killing the node process manually with kill -9, deleting node modules and installing again.

I didn't do anything to mess with the server or app, some changes I did I reverted to see if it what was bothering it (not so likely because the change was simply on one of the components, nothing that would affect networking in any way).

This is my very first time working with React Native and emulators so of course there is a million things I could have done wrong, but this thing bamboozles me because it works fine one time and then suddenly not.

Comment: Happens to me often enough as well on Windows.  If hitting `r` to reload in the Metro window doesn't reconnect it, then restarting Metro is the only reliable option I've found to get it back. I am running a weird hybrid Windows/WSL setup (code & node on wsl, emulator on windows) because of company guidelines, so I always blame that.

Comment: Various restarts didn't help that at all last time. I left it for a few days, when I decided to open up the project again to check it out it was magically solved and never occurred again (but let's not jinx it).